# Is it possible to use CoreLocation/MapKit to find addresses near a Latitude/Longitude?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, mapkit, core-location

I am developing an iPhone app for iOS 6.1 or later. I would like to have a feature that would provide the user a list of addresses that are nearby. I know I can use a geocoder with a reverseGeocodeLocation call to get the address of a specific latitude/longitude. But what I need is not just that address, but also, a few (maybe 10) addresses that are near that address.

The MKLocalSearchRequest doesn't seem to support any kind of search request that would return that information. (I am not searching for hotels, or restaurants, etc., just any valid nearby addresses) Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: maybe by using a CLLocation with a bad horizontalAccuracy for the reverseGeocodeLocation operation? (in order to have multiple values in the callback's NSArray parameter)

Comment: @JeromeDiaz: Tried your idea, but still only get one item in the array. Good idea though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research into other map API's from third parties (Google, Mapquest, Bing) I have still been unable to find one that provides this functionality. The answer to my question therefore appears to be that it currently can't be done. The only solution to my problem was to have a complete list of addresses geocoded in a database. (Fortunately for me, my organization has such a database available.)

Answer (score 0):

There's no API for that, the only thing I can think of is using a for loop and increasing manually latitude/longitude and reverse geocoding.

Comment: My fear with trying to use this is I will hit the Apple servers too much and get blocked.